# How to prove Existence and unicity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove or give a counterexample:

Let $g$ be a continuous extension of a continuous function $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

1. $g$ exists
2. $g$ is unique

I am interested in how one approaches a theorem that hasn't been confirmed to be true yet (in the exercise).

Are there standard methods to prove existence and unicity?

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)= \frac{1}{x-\pi}$ defined from $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ \pi \} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Restrict it to $\mathbb{Q}$  then it stays continuous. But as you can see you cannot extend it to $\pi$. You can extend uniquely a uniformely continous function defined on a dense set of a complete metric space.

Edit: Answer to the second assertion, If f is extendable then the extension is unique.
Suppose $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two continuous extension of $f$. Then $f_1 - f_2$ is continuous and vanishes on a dense subset of a metric space, thus it must be $0$ everywhere: take $x$ in the metric space, by density you can find $x_n \to x$, $x_n$  belong to the dense subset, and by continuity of $f_1 - f_2$, $f_1 - f_2(x) =0$.

Comment: You can add a limit exists if $f$ is locally bounded, and when $f$ can be extended, it's in a unique way, because limits are unique.

Comment: You mean any function $f$ continuous and locally bounded in a dense subset of a metric space is uniquely extendable ?

Comment: @incas This is a counterexample to assertion 1; you may want to add a proof that 2 is true for $g$ continuous.

Comment: I think once 1) is true 2) to. You can take a sequence ${x}_{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ wich converges to $\pi$, in this example. By the continuity of $f$, the $g({x}_{n})=f({x}_{n})$ converges to $g(\pi)$. But this limit is unique. No other limit exists for another function to be continuous at $\pi$.

Comment: @egreg , you are right I forgot the second point. Let me complete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna prove both statements for f uniformly continuous.

**A) We are gonna contruct such a $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.**

Let $\epsilon >0$.
f is uniformly coninuous so: $$\exists \delta >0: \forall |y-x|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(y)-f(x)|< \epsilon\: \: \text{for} \: \: x,y \in \mathbb{Q} \:\:\: (1)$$
Take a $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and fix this element. We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. So there exists a sequence ${({a}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $${a}_{n} \: {\longrightarrow} \: u \:\text{for} \: n \longrightarrow \infty$$
We know by convergence of ${a}_{n}$:
$$\exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall p,q>N: |{a}_{p}-{a}_{q}| < \delta$$
f is continuous so for such $p$ and $q$ we know from (1):
$$|f({a}_{p}) - f({a}_{q})|<\epsilon$$
To summarise:
$$ \forall \epsilon>0,\exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall p,q>N: |f({a}_{p})-f({a}_{q})| < \epsilon$$
So ${(f({a}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. So this has a limit let's call it: $g(u)$.

We have found for every $u \in \mathbb{R}$ a $g(u)$.

**B) We show that $g(u)$ is independent of the sequence ${({a}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we have chosen in part A)**

Take another sequence ${({b}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$${b}_{n} \: {\longrightarrow} \: u \:\text{for} \: n \longrightarrow \infty$$
By the same argument as before we see that ${(f({b}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. We have:
$$|g(u)-f({b}_{n})| \leq |g(u)-f({a}_{n})| + |f({b}_{n})-f({a}_{n})| $$
for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can find $M>0$ such that $$\forall n \geq M: |{b}_{n}-u|<\frac{\delta}{2} \text{and}  |{a}_{n}-u|<\frac{\delta}{2}$$
So $$|{b}_{n}-{a}_{n}| \leq |{a}_{n}-u|+|{b}_{n}-u|<\delta$$
This implies by (1): $$|f({b}_{n})-f({a}_{n})|<\epsilon$$
We know that ${(f({a}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $g(u)$, so by taking $n>M $ big enough we get:
$$|f({b}_{n})-g(u)|  \leq |f({b}_{n})-f({a}_{n})|+|g(u) -f({a}_{n})|<2 \epsilon$$
So ${(f({b}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $g(u)$.
So we can define: $$g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:u \rightarrow g(u)$$

**C) g is continuous**

We have proven in B) that for every sequence ${({b}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, ${(f({b}_{n}))}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $g(u)$. This shows that g is continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$. We still have to prove this for sequences in $\mathbb{R}$.

Take $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We show that $g$ is continuous in $x$. 
So take a sequence ${({x}_{n})}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ wich converges to $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Cause $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we know that for every ${x}_{n}$, there exists an element $y_{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $$|y_{n}-x_{n}|<\frac{\delta}{2}$$
And there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\forall n>N: |x_{n}-x|<\frac{\delta}{2}$$
From these inequalities one can see that $$\forall n> N: |x-y_{n}|< \delta$$
From the continuity of $f$:
$$\forall n> N: |f(x)-f(y_{n})|< \epsilon$$
But also:
$$\forall n> N: |f(x_{n})-f(y_{n})|< \epsilon$$

The last step:
$$|f(x_{n}) - f(x)| \leq |f(x_{n}) - f(y_{n})| + |f(x) - f(y_{n})|< 2\epsilon $$
So we have the following:
$$(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \: \xrightarrow{n \longrightarrow \infty} \: x \:\Rightarrow \: (f(x_{n}))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \: \xrightarrow{n \longrightarrow \infty} \: f(x)$$
So $g$ is continuous at x, hence $g$ is continuous.

**D) The uniqueness**

The uniqueness follows from the construction of $g$. $g$ was constructed by limits of sequences. These limits are unique so $g$ is unique to.